# need VBA help: get debug msg with this delete rows code

Tags: excel, vba

As you can see below, I am trying to delete the entire when any cells in column F has a value of zero. However, my code keeps getting debug at line 3.

```
' DELETES ALL ROWS FROM F2 DOWNWARDS WITH THE VALUE = 0 IN COLUMN F

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, 6).Value) = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What's the error message?  Nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: It says Run-time error "13" Type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I am able to replicate the error you get if one of the cells in the F column returns an error (e.g. a number divided by zero). This happens when your code asks to see if `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0` The following code ignores errors when looping through the cells but tells you which cell(s) that returns this error.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Last As Double
    Dim i As Double

    Last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then
                If Err > 0 Then
                    MsgBox "There is an error in cell " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Address
                    Err.Clear
                Else
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I ran yours. Same thing happened to mine. It would run the code and then delete the rows but it will give me an error message. For your code, it tells me that I need to debug 
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then

Comment: Please see the changes I have made to my answer.